# How can I center the "Buttons" in the Wordpresse editor?

Tags: buttons

I like the reusable buttons in Wordpress, and I want to create a button in the visual editor and I save it as a reusable block, so that I can use it over and over again. but, I never manage to center the button. I have tried to

Comment: When you select the button Block you can just select "Center" from the alignment dropdown. Does this not work? Your question appears to be unfinished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... It seems as if a plugin was blocking this option, that is why I couldn't find it. But, now I disabled the plugin, and it works properly. Thanks!